# How to add notification observers in NSManagedObject subclass to avoid call to unrecognized selector

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data

I've been experiencing a problem with saving managed objects (in a background thread) resulting in calls to unrecognised selectors which seems to be related to the way I'm handling the observation of `NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification`. Intermittently it will fail with `-[NSFetchRequest myManagedObjectContextDidChange:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`. It's not always a `NSFetchRequest`, sometimes it's a `NSKeyValueObservance` or unspecified which makes me believe that the observer is still around after a managed object has been released.

I'm adding and removing the observer to `NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification` as seen below. Is there anything wrong with that?

```c
@interface Foo ()
@property (assign, nonatomic, getter = isObserving) BOOL observing;
@end

@implementation Foo
@synthesize observing = _observing;

- (void)awakeFromInsert {
    [super awakeFromInsert];

    self.addedDate = [NSDate date];
    self.modificationDate = [self.addedDate copy];

    [self commonAwake];
}

- (void)awakeFromFetch {
    [super awakeFromFetch];
    [self commonAwake];
}

- (void)awakeFromSnapshotEvents:(NSSnapshotEventType)flags {
    [super awakeFromSnapshotEvents:flags];
    [self commonAwake];
}

- (void)commonAwake
{
    if (self.isObserving) return;

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(myManagedObjectContextDidChange:)
                                                 name:NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification
                                               object:self.managedObjectContext];
    self.observing = YES;
}

- (void)willTurnIntoFault
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification object:self.managedObjectContext];

    self.observing = NO;
    [super willTurnIntoFault];
}

- (void)myManagedObjectContextDidChange:(NSNotification*)notification {
    NSDictionary *userInfo = [notification userInfo];
    NSMutableSet *changedObjects = [NSMutableSet new];
    NSSet *objects = nil;

    objects = [userInfo objectForKey:NSInsertedObjectsKey];
    [changedObjects unionSet:objects];

    objects = [userInfo objectForKey:NSUpdatedObjectsKey];
    [changedObjects unionSet:objects];

    objects = [userInfo objectForKey:NSDeletedObjectsKey];
    [changedObjects unionSet:objects];

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF IN %@", self.bars];
    NSSet *updatedObjects = [changedObjects filteredSetUsingPredicate:predicate];

    if (updatedObjects.count > 0) {
        NSDate *now = [NSDate date];

        if (self.modificationDate == nil || [now timeIntervalSinceDate:self.modificationDate] > 1.0) {
            self.modificationDate = now;
        }
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: It doesn't seem like the responsibility of an NSManagedObject to handle to NSManagedObjectContextDidChangeNotificaiton.

Comment: I think I agree – I'm also looking into a different approach that involves a object controller looking after these updates and modifying the object accordingly which seems a cleaner way of doing it. However Apple used the same way in a sample project once, I remotely recall a SmartGroup class. Starting out this way I thought it would be good to know.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see when didTurnIntoFault is called. If it is called, try:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self]
```

Note that the contextDidChange notification might be called on a different thread then the didTurnIntoFault. And so you might have a race condition. Make sure the adding and removing of the observe is done on the same thread (which should be the one on which the managedOject and hence the managed object itself was created).

Comment: Wouldn't that be a bit risky to simply call `removeObserver:` as nobody knows if there're any other observers added by Apple in any of the superclasses? Normally when calling this method in `dealloc` it doesn't make a difference but in this case the object is still in parts alive.

Comment: Maybe, but it is an easy way to completely remove self, just to narrow down the search. Still, I think you should focus on making sure all adding and removing (and responding to the notification) is done on one and the same thread.